# is there a code in c# that loads all the elements filled using an array, into the listbox I have once my form is loaded?

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2022

I'm working with Microsoft visual studio 2022 C#, doing a windows application form.( Currently new, been practicing for a month)
I came across this question :

When the form is loaded, the product list box will be filled with each product array element. ( Previously I used to make a button that once clicked loads all the elements but this is the first practice exercise I come across and its relat5ed to the form)
( I filled the products in the listbox using the List method as but I cant seem to make them load into the listbox once i open the form. How do I solve this issue?
Thats how i filled the product using the lists method
List prod = new List()

what i tried: creating a Display Class then call it the form1 code part but I struggled upon an error and that didnt work as shown below

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayProducts();
}
private void DisplayProducts()
{
    AllProducts.Items.Clear();
    AllProducts.Items.AddRange(prod.ToArray());        
}
```

The error is in AllProducts  So I changed it into Products then the Items gave me an error CS0117 is the type of the error
I have tried everything it still gives me an error . Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The simplest way (but not necessarily the right way) is to use an event of the form and start filling the listbox from there. Typical form event would be `Shown`.

Comment: yes I have tried this method. It also didn't work

Comment: You are going to have to show the code that _”doesn’t work”_ … Using a `ListBox` I suggest you simply set its `DataSource` property to the `Array` or `List` you currently have. Without seeing how you are currently doing this… speculation and more questions are all you may get. Please [edit] your question with the necessary code.

Comment: kindly re check the question again, I just edited it

Comment: Where is the `prod` variable declared an instantiated?

Comment: Please post the actual error message

Comment: As already noted, you should provide the exact error you are getting. In my small tests, your posted code works as expected, however we have no idea what `prod` is.

Comment: Can you possibly show me? prod is products which i defined in the lists method

Comment: _”Can you possibly show me?”_ … ? … Show you what? We are asking you to show us what `prod` is… how it is defined and what values does it contain? Please [edit] your question to add the code that defines and fills `prod`.

Comment: I'm asking you to show me since you tried it ( To show me how did you write the code ) To compare mi8ne with yours (Since you're saying it's correct) . Thanks though, I solved it finally using another method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
private void DisplayProducts()
{
    AllProducts.Items.Clear();
    AllProducts.Items.AddRange(prod.ToArray());        
}
```

To:

```
private void DisplayProducts()
{
    //AllProducts.Items.Clear(); this deletes all items in the array. Maybe the point of your error. 
    List<string> prod = new List<string>();
    foreach(string pro in AllProducts) {
    prod.Add(pro);
}
    prod.ToArray();
}
```